# How to install Punkbuster?

Tags: punkbuster

Punkbuster seems it's not running on my machine. I downloaded the PBSetup, but it seems to be just an updater.

BFBC2 complains about PnkbstrA.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the pb service installer.  Download it from WWW.evenbalance.com.  go to the bf2 section.  Click FAQ. Scroll down look for the link to pbsvc. Run that.  It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the installer at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\battlefield bad company 2\install\PunkBuster
```